# how to write test case for functions like shown below in jasmine

Tags: testing, jasmine, case

I have this function:

```
function assignDatesToArbitrationCase(caseID, dateType,dt){
        var urlAssignDate = ConfigService.getBaseURL() +  '/legalcase/legalcasedatetype'
        var assignDateStr = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:leg="http://schemas.arccorp.com/services/airlinesalesreporting/legalCaseDateTypeV1"> ' +
          '<soapenv:Header/>    <soapenv:Body>    <leg:assignToRequest>    <leg:entity> ' +
          '<leg:id legalCaseId="' +  caseID + '" dateTypeId="' +dateType  + '"/> ' +
          '<leg:legalCaseDateTypeDt>' + dateFormatForServer(dt) + '</leg:legalCaseDateTypeDt>' +
          '</leg:entity> </leg:assignToRequest>    </soapenv:Body>    </soapenv:Envelope>';
        return $http({
          url: urlAssignDate,
          method: 'POST',
          data: assignDateStr
        }).then(function (results) {
          var jsonObject = x2js.xml_str2json(results.data);
          return jsonObject;
        })
      }
```

How to write test case for functions like shown below in jasmine?

Comment: Can you please try and clean this question up a little? It is extremely difficult to understand in its current form. Add some background for the problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

So just because you are asking this question, I asume that you are using Jasmine not correctly. I want to answer you why and how you should test. 
If you look to the [jasmine github page](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine). You will find following description of Jasmine:

> Jasmine is a Behavior Driven Development testing framework for
>   JavaScript.

So what is Behavior Driven Development? Here you find a good article at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development)

The principles of BDD are:

- define a test set for the unit first;
- then implement the unit;
- finally verify that the implementation of the unit makes the tests succeed.

So at this point you should understand, why your question is implies a wrong usage of jasmine.

Because you should define your test first and then write the code. If you do so you need to write testable code. If you would make your tests in your first step your functions will look totaly different and you will never ask how to write a test for that function, because before the function exists already the test does.